# Combining two SELECT query that Do not Intersect

Tags: mysql, inner-join, intersection

Suppose we have three tables. Table 2 and 3 intersect with the table 1 but not with each other.
[image]

Two separate INNER JOIN queries get the common column values between table 1 & 2 and table 1 & 3.

Now my question is how to put these two intersections together; simply INNER JOINing these table will not yield any result:

The following would be an ideal result.
[image]

This is as close I have gotten to the desired result, but not close enough.

```html
SELECT * FROM 
 (SELECT `tag_map`.`id`,`resource`.`resource_type_id`,`resource`.`title` FROM `tag_map`
        INNER JOIN `resource`
        ON `tag_map`.`tag_id` = '8'
            AND `tag_map`.`entity_type_id`= '1'
            AND `resource`.`id` = `tag_map`.`entity_id`) AS t1
INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT `name`,`location` FROM `tag_map`        
        INNER JOIN `userinfo`
        ON `tag_map`.`tag_id` = '8'
            AND `tag_map`.`entity_type_id`= '2'
            AND `userinfo`.`id` = `tag_map`.`entity_id`) AS t2
```

The problem with this query is that the JOIN clause mixes the rows and I get this

[image]

Comment: Use `union` instead of `join`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to start querying from the table instersecting both the others, and then `LEFT JOIN` on them:

```
SELECT r.resource_type_id, 
       r.title, 
       u.name 
FROM   tag_map t 
       LEFT JOIN userinfo u 
              ON t.entity_id = u.id 
                 AND t.entity_type_id = '1' 
       LEFT JOIN resource r 
              ON t.entity_id = r.id 
                 AND t.entity_type_id = '2' 
WHERE  ( u.id IS NOT NULL 
          OR r.id IS NOT NULL ) 
       AND t.entity_type_id IN ( '1', '2' ) 
       AND t.tag_id = '1';
```

- See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f791/1)

Comment: Just edited the fiddle to produce the desired result.

Comment: Yes, I just changed some data so that the result meets exactly your desired one. The query didn't change.